# File being loaded on load, why?

Tags: javascript

I am using the code below,

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", registerEvents, false );

    function registerEvents(){
        var frameHeight = window.innerHeight;
        var fixedHeight = document.getElementById( "fixedSection" ).clientHeight;

        document.getElementById( "dynamic_frame" ).height = (frameHeight - fixedHeight)     -50;

        document.getElementById( "home" ).addEventListener( "click", loadPage( "home" ), false );
    }

    function loadPage( page ){
        document.getElementById( "dynamic_frame" ).src = "../htmls/"+ page+ ".html";
}
```

and I thought it would load the file when I click the element that has the ID home, but instead it loads when the webpage first load.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Why is this tagged jQuery when you're not using any jQuery?

Comment: It was suggested. Doesn't really matter

Comment: @Snappiestjack it does matter

Answer (score 2):

This line isn't doing what you think it's doing:

```
loadPage("home")
```

You're using it like a reference to the `loadPage` function, but it's actually *invoking* the `loadPage` function and being used as a reference to the result of that function (which happens to be `undefined`).  So instead of binding the click event to the function, you're immediately invoking the function and binding the click event to `undefined`.

To just reference the function, you need to not use parentheses:

```
loadPage
```

However, since you also want to pass an argument to it, you might need a callback function specifically for that purpose.  Something like this:

```
document.getElementById( "home" ).addEventListener( "click", function () { loadPage( "home" ); }, false );
```

This wraps the call to `loadPage` in an anonymous function, which doesn't need any arguments.  That anonymous function will be invoked on the click event, and all it does internally is invoke the function you want with the argument you want.